# WAN Optimization Resources

Tags: linux, networking, wan

I'm looking for resources on writing software to do WAN optimization. I've googled this and searched SO, but there doesn't seem to be much around. The only things I've found are high-level articles in tech magazines, and info for network admins on how to make use of existing WAN optimization products.

I'm looking for something on the techniques etc. used to write WAN optimization software. It seems to be a dark art, and the people who know how to do it, guard their secrets closely. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start with traffic squeezer - an opensouce WAN Optimizer (http://www.trafficsqueezer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an direct links to good documentation about the art of WAN optimization. However, there are a number of open source projects for different grades of WAN optimization. The largest and most famous (hope I'm right now) is Traffic Squeezer (http://www.trafficsqueezer.org/). There are some documentation about their implementation which you might find useful.

Another big player in the commercial area of WAN optimization is BlueCoat (former Packeteer, http://www.bluecoat.com/). They might have some explaining documentation on their website. At least you should be able to find some whitepapers.

If you have any specific questions I can try to answer them for you.